# How can I use scale_colour_steps with an aes colour variable without Error: Binned scales only support continuous data?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame with x,y coordinates and dozens of columns I want to colour the points by, using scale_colour_steps. I wanted to create multiple plots in a loop using a variable to be passed to aes.

Here is a simple example that shows the error I get:

```
df <- data.frame(
  x = runif(100),
  y = runif(100),
  z1 = rnorm(100)
)

cn <- colnames(df)[3]
gg <- list()

for(i in 1:length(cn)) {
  gg[[i]] <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y, colour = !!cn[i])) +
    geom_point() +
    scale_colour_steps()
}
gg
```

However all I get for this is

```
[[1]]
Error: Binned scales only support continuous data
```

I have tried converting the variable to numeric using as.numeric(as.character(.)) but that hasn't worked for me.

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(
  x = runif(100),
  y = runif(100),
  z1 = rnorm(100)
)

cn <- colnames(df)[3]
gg <- vector('list', length(cn))

for(i in 1:length(cn)) {
  gg[[i]] <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y, colour = .data[[cn[i]]])) +
    geom_point() +
    scale_colour_steps()
}
gg
```

Your attempt should work if you change the colour part as `colour = !!sym(cn[i]))` in your code. However, it is now preferred to use `.data` pronoun instead of `!!sym()`.