# Error: Binned scales only support continuous data ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to colour my ggplot using the viridis colour package. I am plotting factor varaible, where one factor has three levels and one factor has 6 levels.

This is my code

```
ggplot (tiering, aes (Participant.Type,..count..))+geom bar(aes(fill = Tier))+ theme classic()+ gqtitle ("Main phenotypes") + labs (x = "Participant Category",y="Frequency") + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle
: 90, just = 0.5)) + scale_y_continuous (limits = c(0,300)) + scale fill viridis b()
```

This gives me the following error "Binned scales only support continuous data".

I have [looked at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65802681/how-can-i-use-scale-colour-steps-with-an-aes-colour-variable-without-error-binn)and googled how to fix the error, but have been unsuccessful in getting the colours right or the count displayed. This is where my plot is now[image]

Comment: Do you want `scale_fill_viridis_d` here since the categories are discrete?

Comment: I have tried scale_fill_viridis(option ="plasma", discrete = F) as well and it didn't work. I don't think the scale_fill_viridis_d is for discrete, I think that was one of the color schemes as I understood it.

Comment: Tier is a discrete category (ie Tier3 is not "3x" Tier1, and they are presumably encoded as character strings), so you need to use a discrete scale, like `scale_fill_viridis_d()` or by leaving out `discrete = F`.

Comment: When it comes to function aliases for `scale_fill_viridis_*`, `_d()` stands for discrete. `_c()` is for continuous data, and `_b()` is for binning continuous data. Those function names are different than the four colormap palettes in viridis, the default of which is called "viridis" or "D".

Comment: I don't there are enough *smack the face* emojis for this. Thank you, Jon for your help.